# Setting a default browser on a respin

Tags: lubuntu, chromium, browser

I'm creating a respin off of Lubuntu 20.04.1. I installed Lubuntu and made some customizations to it - one of which is Chromium (the Snap version). I've made Chromium my default browser in 2 ways (because it seems there are multiple ways of defining the default browser):

- Setting the Web Browser variable in LXQT Session Settings
- Selecting "Make Chromium the default browser" in the Chromium settings

I set this TWICE! It should work, so I test it:

- sensible-browser              Brings up Chromium
- xdg-open *some site*    Brings up Chromium

I now make a respin based on this system. All of my customizations work perfectly EXCEPT that Firefox is my default browser in the respin.

All of the files were copied, so I'm not sure what got lost in the respin. What should I be looking at to see why Chromium is not my browser?

Comment: Maybe check https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-default-settings  esp. the mimeapps.list (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/lubuntu-default-settings/filelist) which results in /etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu/mimeapps.list  (see https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/solved-chromium-google-chrome-keeps-nagging-about-not-being-the-default-browser/500) ; *I recall discussion in our phab instance but a quick search didn't find that hence the discourse link*

Comment: @guiverc I'm not really sure why there are so many places that define the default browser, but what you suggested seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: You made reference to methods via GUI, where was my thinking was how I would change it via package for new installs, or via upgrade to existing installs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-default-settings

esp. `mimeapps.list`

(https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/lubuntu-default-settings/filelist)

which results in `/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu/mimeapps.list`

(see https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/solved-chromium-google-chrome-keeps-nagging-about-not-being-the-default-browser/500 ; I recall a discussion in our *phab* instance but a quick search didn't find that hence the discourse link I did find)

I'm no expert, nor a *dev*, but it's how I would change it for new installs, or for existing installs via normal upgrade process (*it's also a package I've touched/changed for a prior release*)