# Epiphany - how to switch off displaying PDF document and save it instead?

Tags: 20.04, pdf, settings, epiphany

I have installed epiphany - a simple fast browser.

But I would prefer to download PDF instead of displaying it by the default viewer.

Do you know how to set up saving as the default action for a click at PDF link?

Thank you for any hint. :-)

JK

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; but have tagged your questions as a Debian/Ubuntu workflow or packaging issue?  How does Debian/Ubuntu workflow relate?  What OS & release (inc. desktop if not a default Ubuntu Desktop install) are you using?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and [*official* flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Ok, I change it to Ubuntu topic. It is the same in Ubuntu. I cannot switch off PDF display on Epiphany in Lubuntu 20.04 as well. Thanks for a help. :-)

Comment: FYI:  You're aware that Lubuntu 20.04 LTS was a *flavor* of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and came with 3 years of supported life? (refer https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-20-04-lts-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/ reaching the end of its three year supported life) with 5 years applying to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu base but not *flavors*.   *Lubuntu uses LXQt so use of a GNOME web browser isn't very efficient; epiphany being a GNOME Project browser uses GNOME settings specifically*

Comment: Dear Mr. Guiverc, I do not want to make any problems to anybody. So give me a hint how to improve my question not to harm anybody. I have a few PC's in my household. One is on Debian, the rest are on various types of Lubuntu. If I have epiphany on any of those computers - my question is how to prevent displaying PDF and download it instead. I do not think that I want to harm Lubuntu by asking this question.

Comment: Lubuntu may no longer provide support; but *flavors* of 20.04 are still on-topic on this site (*I see a Lubuntu 20.04 LTS system as a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the LXQt desktop myself*), I didn't close-vote or provide on-topic link, just left an FYI informational link. I don't see `epiphany` as efficient on Lubuntu (and I like `epiphany`) but that's how I see it (*I used `epiphany` regularly when I collected news for Ubuntu News years ago*), and I use Debian too but that **is** off-topic here. Myself I won't provide support for a 20.04 *flavor* (as some others won't too), but many will.

Comment: There are many questions/answers already on this site (eg. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273652/setting-a-default-browser-on-a-respin) though that isn't what I was looking for (there are 2-3 closer than that, but higher-ranked questions are easier to find & anything obscure like you won't won't likely be highly rated)

Comment: Dear Mr. Guiverc, I am speaking about setting up Epiphany. As I see you do not know the answer. So I thank you for your effort and I have to wait for someone else. Sincerely JK